# Css: div sticking to top of parent container

Tags: css, html

my div inside a parent container should have a margin of 20px from the top from the container instead the margin top applys to the parent container...

```css
#rules-panel {
 background-color:blue;
 width:80%;
 margin:0 auto;
 height:800px;
}

#rules-panel .box {
 margin:20px;
  margin-top:20px; /* why isn't the margin working */
 background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="rules-panel">

 <div class="box">
  <p>THIS IS div</p>
  <p>THIS IS div</p>
  <p>THIS IS div</p>
  <p>THIS IS div</p>
  <p>THIS IS div</p>
 </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: @Lewis, no he simply need to add `overflow:hidden`

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that. +1

Comment: @TemaniAfif it worked. Could you please explain why overflow:hidden was needed im confused ?

Comment: everything is explained within the duplicate question :) this is called margin-collpasing